# RxJS: Observable.never() keeps like subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using rxjs 5.5.6.

I've created this code in order to show the behavior:

```
Observable.of(1, 2)
    .do(a => {
        console.log(a);
        let d:string = null;
        let r = d.length;  // it raises an null exception
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log("error catched");  //exception is capture here
        return Observable.never();
    })
    .subscribe();
```

I was expecting that the output is:

```
1
error catched
2
error catched
```

However, the output is:

```
1
error catched
```

It means, the subscription terminates despite of an `Observable.never()` is returned on `.catch(...)` method chain.

Any ideas?

**REAL CASE**

```
this.subs = Observable
    .merge(this.$searchQuery, this.$lazyQuery)
    .do(() => this.loadingPage())
    .map(filter => this.buildURL(user, app, filter))
    .switchMap(url => this.service.getItemsFromService(url))
    .map(response => this.buildPage(response))
    .do(page => this.loadedPage(page))
    .catch(() => {
        this.loadedPage(pojo.Page.EMPTY);
        return Observable.never();
    })
    .takeUntil(this.$unsubscribe)
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: Why are you [deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56040561/angular-rxjs-observable-never-doesnt-work-subscription-terminates) and reposting this same question? Do you think this will get you an answer??

Comment: What do you mean by `the subscription terminates`?

Comment: Subscription should continue processing `2` value instead of stopping...

Answer (score 1):

You get the output

```
1 
error catched
```

because the first value throws an error in `tap` which is propagated through the `onError` channel which halts the sequence. With `catch` you catch this error and move on to the next sequence (`never`), but the first sequence (`of(1,2)`) is still halted. So after `1` throws an error `2` is never processed by `tap`.

After you return `never` in `catch` no value is emitted and the Observable never completes. If you add logs inside `subscribe` for the `next`, `error` and `complete` callbacks you will see that they are never executed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes all the explanation by @frido is correct. With that answer I would like to add:

If you want to capture any error occuring in any particular Observable itself(say an HTTP request) then you need to handle it in that particular erroring Observable.

```
  let correct = Observable.of("correct")
  let inCorrect = Observable.throw('inCorect')

  let obs = [inCorrect, correct];
  let handledObs = obs.map(eachObs => {
    return eachObs.catch((e) => {
      console.log("Individual handler, Good Catch!");
      return Observable.of("I am tampered");
    })
  })

  forkJoin(...handledObs)
  .do(a => {
      console.log(a);
  })
  .catch(() => {
      console.log("error catched");
      return Observable.never();
  })
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(`data`, data)
  },(e) => {
      console.log(`error`, e)
  });

}
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7mmhn7?file=src/app/app.component.ts

---

**EDIT**

However when I look at your code, it looks to me that you are trying to log something and the returned data may not have a `length` property, even in that case you want to proceed with the stream. If this is true then you can add a simple `try` `catch` under `do()`

```
  from([1, 2])
  .do(a => {
      try {
        console.log(a);
        let d:string = null;
        let r = d.length;
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(`catched under do`, e)
      }
  })
  .catch(() => {
      console.log("error catched");
      return Observable.of('catched');
  })
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(`data`, data)
  },(e) => {
      console.log(`error`, e)
  });
```

Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcrava?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I've added my **real case** in post. As you can see, it tries to make a request to a service. Could you take a look a look? I hope no more code is needed...

Comment: @Jordi what causes the exception? `page => this.loadedPage(page)` under `do`?