# RxJS: Nested catch vs raw catch

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've detected an behavior I'm struggling to figure out, but I definitely lost the train of thoughts.

**Current working** observable is:

```
Observable
    .merge(this.eager$, this.lazy$)
    .map(() => this.buildURL())
    .switchMap(url =>
        this.service.getItemsFromSservice(url)
        .map(response => this.buildPage(response))
        .catch(() => Observable.of(pojo.Page.EMPTY))
    );
```

I mean, when an exception is raised due to http comunication error, the exception is picked up by nested `.catch(...)` and returns an empty `Page` and subscription goes on without any more issues.

However, if I move nested `.map(...).catch(...)` into the "main line" chain, **subscription doesn't work**:

```
Observable
    .merge(this.eager$, this.lazy$)
    .map(() => this.buildURL())
    .switchMap(url => this.service.getItemsFromSservice(url))
    .map(response => this.buildPage(response))
    .catch(() => Observable.of(pojo.Page.EMPTY)
);
```

Using above code, when an http error is raised, subscription terminates. **Why?**

where:

```
this.eager$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(this.searchButton, 'click');
this.lazy$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(this.lazyButton, 'click');
```

Comment: As shown in my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041453/rxjs-observable-never-keeps-like-subscription/56041827#56041827 , in the nested catch, I wasn't returning an error so the stream continues. Had I returned an error, it would had discontinued even in that case. **When you are returning Observable.of(pojo.Page.EMPTY)**, it is a success, had you returned **Observable.throw(pojo.Page.EMPTY)** your stream would had stopped

Answer (score 1):

Because when an observable emits an error, it never, ever emits anything ever again. The error state is a terminal state.

In the first snippet, every time the outer observable (created by `merge()`) emits, a new, inner observable is created by `switchMap()`. If this inner observale emits an error, then this error is caught and an empty page is emitted instead of the error. The inner observable has reached its terminal state and will never emit again, but the outer observable has never emitted any error. If the outer observable emits a new event, then a brand new inner observable is created again by `switchMap()`.

In the second snippet, the outer observable does emit an error if the inner one emits an error, since it isn't caught and replaced by an empty page. So the outer observable reaches its terminal, error state and never emits again.

In a synchronous world, you can see it as the different between this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  try {
    doSomething(i);
  }
  catch (e) {
    // too bad
  }
  console.log(i);
}
```

and

```
try {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    doSomething(i);
  }
  console.log(i);
}
catch (e) {
  // too bad
}
```

In the first snippet, all the numbers from 0 to 1000 will be printed even if `doSomething()` throws an exception, since the exception thrown by doSomething() is caught and ignored.

In the second one however, the exception is thrown, and thus interrupts the outer loop. Which means that not all the numbers will be printed if `doSomething()` throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the main stream has errored, and according to rxjs, it cannot be used anymore. The nested catch works because it just says that `getItemsFromSservice` has an error, and it will keep listening for emits from `this.eager$` and `this.lazy$`.

Maybe this will work, but haven't tested it at all:

```
const page$ = Observable
    .merge(this.eager$, this.lazy$)
    .map(() => this.buildURL())
    .switchMap(url => this.service.getItemsFromSservice(url))
    .map(response => this.buildPage(response))
);

this.page$
  .catch(() => page$.startWith(pojo.Page.EMPTY))
  .subscribe((page) => console.log(page));
```